# How to adjust the width of columns in this table?

Tags: tables

I am trying to make this table:

```
\begin{table}[]
\centering
\caption{}
\label{tab:my-table}
\resizebox{\columnwidth}{!}{%
\begin{tabular}{lcccc}
\hline
 & \multicolumn{4}{c}{Stacked Differences, 1990-2000 and 2000-2007} \\ \cline{2-5} 
 & (1) & (2) & (3) & (4) \\ \hline
 & \multicolumn{4}{c}{A. Change in Private Employment-to-Population Ratio -- All} \\ \cline{2-5} 
Adjusted EURO5 Exposure to Robots & 0.00 & 0.00 & 0.00 & 0.00 \\
 & 0.00 & 0.00 & 0.00 & 0.00 \\
Observations & 0.00 & 0.00 & 0.00 & 0.00 \\
R-squared & 0.00 & 0.00 & 0.00 & 0.00 \\ \cline{2-5} 
 & \multicolumn{4}{c}{B. Change in Private Employment-to-Population Ratio -- Women} \\ \cline{2-5} 
Adjusted EURO5 Exposure to Robots & 0.00 & 0.00 & 0.00 & 0.00 \\
 & 0.00 & 0.00 & 0.00 & 0.00 \\
Observations & 0.00 & 0.00 & 0.00 & 0.00 \\
R-squared & 0.00 & 0.00 & 0.00 & 0.00 \\ \cline{2-5} 
 & \multicolumn{4}{c}{C. Change in Private Employment-to-Population Ratio -- Men} \\ \cline{2-5} 
Adjusted EURO5 Exposure to Robots & 0.00 & 0.00 & 0.00 & 0.00 \\
 & 0.00 & 0.00 & 0.00 & 0.00 \\
Observations & 0.00 & 0.00 & 0.00 & 0.00 \\
R-squared & 0.00 & 0.00 & 0.00 & 0.00 \\ \cline{2-5} 
 & \multicolumn{4}{c}{Covariates} \\ \cline{2-5} 
Time Dummies and Census Divisions & Yes & Yes & Yes & Yes \\
Demographics & No & Yes & Yes & Yes \\
Industry Shares & No & No & Yes & Yes \\
Trade, Routine Jobs & No & No & No & Yes \\ \hline
\end{tabular}%
}
\end{table}
```

The output is:

[image]

How to make the columns (2-5) of equal width?

Comment: Any news? You got nice answer. Is it useful for you?  As I see, so far any answer you got, you not estimate to be worth to be accepted.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you start by changing all instances of `& \multicolumn{4}{c}` to `\multicolumn{5}{@{}l@{}}`. Then, get rid of the `\resizebox` directive and insert a `\centering` instruction. Optionally, load the `booktabs` package, get rid of the `\cline` directives, and replace the instances of `\hline` with `\toprule` and `\bottomrule` as needed.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{booktabs} % for well-spaced horizontal rules
\begin{document}
\begin{table}
\centering
\caption{Stacked Differences, 1990--2000 and 2000--2007\strut}
\label{tab:my-table}
\begin{tabular}{@{} lcccc @{}}
\toprule
 & (1) & (2) & (3) & (4) \\ 
\cmidrule(l){2-5}
\multicolumn{5}{@{}l@{}}{A. Change in Private Employment-to-Population Ratio -- All} \\ 
Adjusted EURO5 Exposure to Robots & 0.00 & 0.00 & 0.00 & 0.00 \\
               & 0.00 & 0.00 & 0.00 & 0.00 \\
Observations   & 0.00 & 0.00 & 0.00 & 0.00 \\
R-squared      & 0.00 & 0.00 & 0.00 & 0.00 \\ 
\addlinespace % add a bit of vertical whitespace
\multicolumn{5}{@{}l@{}}{B. Change in Private Employment-to-Population Ratio -- Women} \\ 
Adjusted EURO5 Exposure to Robots & 0.00 & 0.00 & 0.00 & 0.00 \\
               & 0.00 & 0.00 & 0.00 & 0.00 \\
Observations   & 0.00 & 0.00 & 0.00 & 0.00 \\
R-squared      & 0.00 & 0.00 & 0.00 & 0.00 \\ 
\addlinespace
\multicolumn{5}{@{}l@{}}{C. Change in Private Employment-to-Population Ratio -- Men} \\ 
Adjusted EURO5 Exposure to Robots & 0.00 & 0.00 & 0.00 & 0.00 \\
               & 0.00 & 0.00 & 0.00 & 0.00 \\
Observations   & 0.00 & 0.00 & 0.00 & 0.00 \\
R-squared      & 0.00 & 0.00 & 0.00 & 0.00 \\ 
\addlinespace 
\multicolumn{5}{@{}l@{}}{Covariates} \\ 
Time Dummies and Census Divisions & Yes & Yes & Yes & Yes \\
Demographics        & No & Yes & Yes & Yes \\
Industry Shares     & No & No  & Yes & Yes \\
Trade, Routine Jobs & No & No  & No  & Yes \\ 
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```